# Parallel two dependent Actions in Spark Streaming

Tags: java, apache-spark, kafka-consumer-api

HI I am new to Spark Streaming and below is my requirement

My Consumer Streaming application is recieving a messages (Json Files) from a topic and I need to perform two actions on incoming files..

1. Get the required fileds from a json file and write it to Hbase
2. Transform some fields and write few things to another Kafka topic.

I know I can do these two actions sequentially. But is there anyway we can run these two actions parallely ?

If yes,  Can we have some dependency between two actions? Like if Action 1 fails while writing a particular file to Hbase, we should stop the Action 2 for a particular message as well..  is it possible?

Can anyone suggest a better approach?

Comment: These two requirements are clearly in conflict. Also if you operate on the same input, parallel execution of tasks might actually degrade performance, as it might require caching or repeated disk IO and parsing (not to mention issues with scheduling constraints). If you want to make the second one work, create a composite sink which will handle dependency on the record level and tune parallelism globally on the stream level.